# Changing # of vector points on a plotted circle in p5.js with dat.GUI

Tags: javascript, vector, processing, p5.js, dat.gui

I am trying to create some custom shapes in p5js by plotting a certain number of vertices (determined by `stepCount`) in a circular shape and then connecting the points.

Depending on the `stepCount`, the shape can be a line, rectangle, pentagon, hexagon, etc., all the way up to a circle. When I hardcode the stepCount and refresh the page, the changes are reflected as intended.

The problem is that I want to use dat.GUI to manipulate the `stepCount` live from the page. When I do this, I get a flashing outline with the intended shape clipped out of it.

This is my code below:

```js
let p;
let x;
let y;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  p = new Planet();
  console.log("Planet generated.");
  let gui = new dat.GUI();
  gui.add(p, 'radius', 0, 500);
  gui.add(p, 'stepCount', 0, 50)

}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background(100);
  makePlanet();
}

function Planet() {
  this.radius = 200;
  this.angle = 0;
  this.stepCount = 20;
  this.step = TWO_PI / this.stepCount;
  this.angle = 0;
}

function makePlanet() {
  beginShape();
  for (i = 0; i < p.stepCount + 1; i++) {
    x = p.radius * sin(p.angle);
    y = p.radius * cos(p.angle);
    vertex(windowWidth / 2 - x, windowHeight / 2 - y);
    p.angle = p.angle + p.step;
    if (i >= p.stepCount) {
      endShape();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.5/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
```

I know that this has something to do with `p.angle = p.angle + p.step` running in a loop, but I'm having trouble figuring out whether the solution is mathematical or lies in the way I'm storing the variables in `Planet()`.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated, I just want to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to [`round`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/round) the `p.stepCount` to an integral value. The angle for one step depends on the number of steps, so it has to be recalculated (`p.steps`). `p.angle` should be reset in every frame, to start at beginning:

```js
function makePlanet() {
    // round stepCount
    stepCount =  round(p.stepCount);
    // calculate step angle 
    p.steps = TWO_PI / stepCount;
    // reset start angle
    p.angle = 0;
    // create shape
    beginShape();
    for (i = 0; i <= stepCount; i++) {
        x = p.radius * sin(p.angle);
        y = p.radius * cos(p.angle);
        vertex(windowWidth / 2 - x, windowHeight / 2 - y);
        p.angle = p.angle + p.steps;
        if (i >= stepCount) {
            endShape();
        }
    }
}
```

Further more, the minimum number of steps should be 3:

```js
gui.add(p, 'stepCount', 3, 50)
```

See the example

```js
let p, x, y;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    p = new Planet();
    console.log("Planet generated.");
    let gui = new dat.GUI();
    gui.add(p, 'radius', 0, 500);
    gui.add(p, 'stepCount', 3, 50)
}

function windowResized() {
    resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
    background(100);
    makePlanet();
}

function Planet() {
    this.radius = 50;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.stepCount = 5
    this.step = TWO_PI / this.stepCount;
    this.angle = 0;
}

function makePlanet() {
    // round stepCount
    stepCount =  round(p.stepCount);
    // calculate step angle 
    p.steps = TWO_PI / stepCount;
    // reset start angle
    p.angle = 0;
    // create shape
    beginShape();
    for (i = 0; i <= stepCount; i++) {
        x = p.radius * sin(p.angle);
        y = p.radius * cos(p.angle);
        vertex(windowWidth / 2 - x, windowHeight / 2 - y);
        p.angle = p.angle + p.steps;
        if (i >= stepCount) {
            endShape();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.5/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Since I wanted to add the capability for drawing lines and points, I was also able to reach a solution by changing the following: 

`gui.add(p, 'stepCount', 3, 50)` to `gui.add(p, 'stepCount', 0, 50).step(1)`